# R scatterplot with boxplots adjacent to x and y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, boxplot

I try to do such a plot using ggplot2 in R ? Check the panel g, h j, l or m of the figure below . So a scatterplot with boxplots next to the main plot. I tried the method described here but it didn't work at all http://www.r-bloggers.com/scatterplot-with-marginal-boxplots/ ...

FYI the figure is from this article : http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26437030

Thank you
[image]

Comment: please post some data and the code you tried along with what exactly did not work.

Comment: I found my error. I had an issue in the grid package. I'll post my function as answer.

Comment: @NicoBxl cowplot does this nicely. Using plots from your answer.
ggdraw() +
  draw_plot(p1, 0.2, 0, width = 0.8, height = 0.8) +
  draw_plot(p2, 0, 0, width = 0.2, height = 0.8) +
  draw_plot(p3, 0.2, 0.8, width = 0.8, height = 0.2)

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution. I just don't know how to put the y boxplot to the left of the plot and not to the right. I guess I have to change the gtable_add_grob parameter.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)

a.x <- rnorm(20,5,1)
a.y <- rnorm(20,10,2)
b.x <- rnorm(10,20,2)
b.y <- rnorm(10,5,2)
x <- data.frame(x=c(a.x,b.x),y=c(a.y,b.y),col=c(rep("A",20),rep("B",10)))

p1 <- ggplot(x,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point(aes(color=col))+stat_smooth(method = "lm",se=F,colour="black",linetype=2,size=0.5)+theme_bw()+theme(legend.position="none")
p2 <- ggplot(x,aes(x=col,y=y,color=col))+geom_boxplot()+theme_bw()+theme(legend.position="none",axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank(),axis.text.y=element_blank())
p3 <- ggplot(x,aes(x=col,y=x,color=col))+geom_boxplot()+coord_flip()+theme_bw()+theme(legend.position="none",axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank())

gt1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
gt2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))
gt3 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p3))

maxWidth <- unit.pmax(gt1$widths[2:3], gt2$widths[2:3])
maxHeight <- unit.pmax(gt1$heights[4:5], gt3$heights[4:5])


gt1$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gt2$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)

gt1$heights[4:5] <- as.list(maxHeight)
gt3$heights[4:5] <- as.list(maxHeight)

gt <- gtable(widths = unit(c(4, 1), "null"), height = unit(c(1, 4), "null"))

gt <- gtable_add_grob(gt, gt1, 2, 1)
gt <- gtable_add_grob(gt, gt2, 2, 2)
gt <- gtable_add_grob(gt, gt3, 1, 1)


grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gt)
```

And the result :

[image]